# How to separate initials from last names in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table where i have initials and last names in the column B starting from the second row as the first row has headings.

How to create a macro so that it goes through every name and separates initials from last name in the following fashion:

Column B - first initial, column C - second initial if it exists and column D is the last name which can contain two names. Initials are always one letter and a second initial might not exists as per below example:

T W Stephens will be in following columns as
Column B - T, Column C - W, Column D - Stephens

S Russ
Column B - S, Column C - empty, Column D - Russ

P De Costa
Column B - P, Column C - empty, Column D - De Costa

S B John Paul
Column B - S, Column C - B, Column D - John Paul

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you going to attempt anything yourself or just wait for someone else to do your work for you??

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I do not know how do it unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a           As Variant
Dim b           As Variant
Dim x           As Variant
Dim s           As String
Dim i           As Long
Dim j           As Long

a = Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value
ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To 3)

For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
    x = Split(Trim(a(i, 1)))
    j = j + 1: s = ""

    If Len(Trim(x(0))) = 1 Then b(j, 1) = x(0): s = x(0) & " "
    If Len(Trim(x(1))) = 1 Then b(j, 2) = x(1): s = s & x(1) & " "
    b(j, 3) = Trim(Replace(a(i, 1), s, ""))
Next i

Range("B2").Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)).Value = b
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Yasser. Most names are split ok, but there were such names as C Cutter which were split as C utter, D Drew showed as D rew, M D Mallen showed as M D allen

Comment: @BatyrNazarov Try adding spaces: `b(j, 3) = Trim(Replace(Replace(a(i, 1), b(j, 1) & " ", ""), b(j, 2) & " ", ""))`

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for the help. It put double names into the column D but merged them. For example it shows P Baker Mowlem in column B as P and in column D as BakerMowlem. Is it possible to separate last names so that they show Baker Mowlem in column D. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Rory. Yasser helped with the code. So it works now